# Not able to make app iphone only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

### Problem

I have created a build for my app on iphone only mode by setting the target device family to `1` in Xcode 7.2.

But when I run the build on iPad, firstly it shows a warning in safari like the image I have shared.

Nevertheless I was able to install the build and the build was running on iPad also.

**Below is my screenshot of safari screen:**
http://prntscr.com/dmhd1s

### What we want

We want that app not to be able to run on the iPad, but only only iPhone specific. The app is not live, it is on testing mode.

Due to this reason app got rejected from the app store because we have made app only for iPhone not for iPad.

Comment: Apple strictly tells that any application should run on iPad's as well at least with 3GS resolution. So give proper constraints and you are good to go.
You cannot restrict iPad users not to download your application.

Comment: We dont want to make it for iPad. how to restrict it. we have one another app that is working on iPhone only but when we download it on ipad it wont work. It is live